# How can a module file receive an input from a list?

Tags: python, python-module

I am trying to set up modules, and I am fairly new to modules. I have searched a bit online and can't find an answer to this!

I am trying to create a module with some code I made for QuickSort, however I am unsure how to get an input from other files.

My code in the module is:

```
# An algorithm to sort a list of random numbers using QuickSort

def mainSortBody(arrayToSort, begin, end):

    compareVarI = arrayToSort[begin]
    lower = begin + 1
    upper = end

    while True:

        while lower <= upper and arrayToSort[upper] >= compareVarI:
            upper = upper - 1

        while lower <= upper and arrayToSort[lower] <= compareVarI:
            lower = lower + 1

        if lower <= upper:
            arrayToSort[lower], arrayToSort[upper] = arrayToSort[upper], arrayToSort[lower]
        else:
            break

    arrayToSort[begin], arrayToSort[upper] = arrayToSort[upper], arrayToSort[begin]

    return upper


def speedSort(arrayToSort, begin, end):
    if begin >= end:
        return

    p = mainSortBody(arrayToSort, begin, end)
    speedSort(arrayToSort, begin, p-1)
    speedSort(arrayToSort, p+1, end)

def sort(arrayToSort):
    speedSort(arrayToSort, 0, len(arrayToSort) - 1)

arrayToSort = []

sort(arrayToSort)
print(arrayToSort)
```

My code in the other file

```
import main

array = [21,31,348,283,128,348,394,586,378,1923,1381782432,12348,13284]
main.sort(array)
```

The Output

```
[]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I guess just call the `speedSort` in your other file and pass the list as an argument?

Comment: Your quicksort code is a bit lacking in terms of `return`'s — re module organization, the naming is unusual but what you do is correct .

Comment: Thanks for the help!

I'm fairly new to coding and not too good with variable naming because making the code takes long enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe you have it a bit backwards. `main.py` should not be the module that is imported, as it should be the, well, main part of the program. You import what you need in `main.py` and run it there.

Here's how you could do it:

#### quicksort.py

```
def mainSortBody(arrayToSort, begin, end):

    compareVarI = arrayToSort[begin]
    lower = begin + 1
    upper = end

    while True:

        while lower <= upper and arrayToSort[upper] >= compareVarI:
            upper = upper - 1

        while lower <= upper and arrayToSort[lower] <= compareVarI:
            lower = lower + 1

        if lower <= upper:
            arrayToSort[lower], arrayToSort[upper] = (
                arrayToSort[upper],
                arrayToSort[lower],
            )
        else:
            break

    arrayToSort[begin], arrayToSort[upper] = arrayToSort[upper], arrayToSort[begin]

    return upper


def speedSort(arrayToSort, begin, end):
    if begin >= end:
        return

    p = mainSortBody(arrayToSort, begin, end)
    speedSort(arrayToSort, begin, p - 1)
    speedSort(arrayToSort, p + 1, end)


def sort(arrayToSort):
    speedSort(arrayToSort, 0, len(arrayToSort) - 1)
```

#### main.py

```
from quicksort import sort

if __name__ == "__main__":
    array = [21, 31, 348, 283, 128, 348, 394, 586, 378, 1923, 1381782432, 12348, 13284]
    sort(array)

    print(array)
```

Comment: I have tried this and it now works and prints an output, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped, consider accepting one of the answers if they helped solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the **tester file**; the file you would run is *test.py*:
the *test.py* should look like this:

```
from main import sort # importing the sort function from main.py

array = [21,31,348,283,128,348,394,586,378,1923,1381782432,12348,13284]
sort(array)
print(array) # printing the array as the function returns None
```

and the *main.py*:

```
# An algorithm to sort a list of random numbers using QuickSort

def mainSortBody(arrayToSort, begin, end):

    compareVarI = arrayToSort[begin]
    lower = begin + 1
    upper = end

    while True:

        while lower <= upper and arrayToSort[upper] >= compareVarI:
            upper = upper - 1

        while lower <= upper and arrayToSort[lower] <= compareVarI:
            lower = lower + 1

        if lower <= upper:
            arrayToSort[lower], arrayToSort[upper] = arrayToSort[upper], arrayToSort[lower]
        else:
            break

    arrayToSort[begin], arrayToSort[upper] = arrayToSort[upper], arrayToSort[begin]

    return upper


def speedSort(arrayToSort, begin, end):
    if begin >= end:
        return

    p = mainSortBody(arrayToSort, begin, end)
    speedSort(arrayToSort, begin, p-1)
    speedSort(arrayToSort, p+1, end)

def sort(arrayToSort):
    speedSort(arrayToSort, 0, len(arrayToSort) - 1)

# only keep the functions in this file; so removed the redundant parts or else they would also be executed.
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: You should explain what you changed to fix the issue, and also avoid wildcard imports when possible, it could be instead `from main import sort`